# Babel 7 equivalent of babel-register?

Tags: webpack, gulp, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-register

I am learning how to use Webpack 4 by building a Webpack 4 & Gulp 4 boilerplate. Gulp to handle Sass etc and Webpack to handle the JS.

The tutorial I followed gave me this command to run for the build process:

```
NODE_ENV=production gulp build --require babel-register --gulpfile tasks
```

And that makes sense, however, the tutorial I was following had Babel 6 in the example. I have upgraded my project to Babel 7 using `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env` instead of `babel-core` and `babel-preset-env`.

However, this means that the `--require babel-register` portion of the build command no longer works. What would be the workaround to get Babel 7 to compile my Gulp/Wepback files so I can continue to use `import gulp from 'gulp'`.

Excuse the poor terminology and poor explanation, I've been in Gulp 4 alone for so long, it's like starting again!

Answer (score 0):

---

**Update 17/04/2019**

After forking the tutorial and updating all the packages I have it working with the changes listed in this pull request

https://github.com/PascalAOMS/gulp4-webpack/pull/1

---

**Original Post 06/04/2019**

I am working through what sounds like a similar tutorial (https://css-tricks.com/combine-webpack-gulp-4/ and was hitting a similar issue - the first time it hits an import statement it complains.

I made a fresh repository to just get the import statements working (ignoring the webpack stuff for the moment) and got them working with @babel/register in [this repository](https://github.com/Marcamillian/babel-register-demo/tree/babel-register-docs) working from [this documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register/).

I tried putting it into the node script definition using the `--require` flag though it doesn't seem to like it (I'll fiddle around some more) but what got it working for me

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "use_import": "gulp --gulpfile tasks"
  },
  "author": "Marc Vousden",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3"
    "gulp": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

```
// index.js
require('@babel/register');

const subtask = require('./subtask').default;

exports.default = (cb)=>{
  console.log("loaded index")
  subtask()
  cb()
}
```

- At the top of the gulpfile (in my case tasks/index) use `require("@babel/register")` *This should make babel process other require statements so that import works*
- Use require statements to get scripts that use import statements inside them *It seems that the require statement returns an object with a key/value pair for the default export so I had to pop .default on the end*

I'm still working through things so I will update if I get the whole process working but for now it might get you a little further down the track.

(also - I completely forgot to add a .babelrc file in my panic for a while)